# Remembering a colour

Tags: serial

Hey guys I have a led grid. it's 8 sides that are addressable with the bytes `'1'` through `'8'`. (a Kinect is sending these bytes through processing)  I have also creates three buttons in processing that change the colour of the leds. (`'R'`,`'G'`,`'B'`).

I'm stuck in the code, my code now when receiving the bytes: `'R'`, `'G'` or `'B'` changes all leds to that colour. instead of remembering the colour and only lighting up the sides determined by the `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'` values.

I need it to remember the chosen R,G,B colour until another colour is chosen and only  use the bytes `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'` to select what side of the grid to light up.

Here is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <FastLED.h>

#define LED_PIN     6
#define NUM_LEDS    360

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB saved_color;

void setup()
{
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(50);

  Serial.begin(9600);

  FastLED.clear();
  FastLED.show();

}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 1)
  {
    int incomingByte = Serial.read();

    if (incomingByte > '0' && incomingByte < '9')
    {
      FastLED.clear();
    }


    if (incomingByte == 'R') {
      saved_color = CRGB(255, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == 'G') {
      saved_color = CRGB(0, 255, 0);
    }
    else if (incomingByte == 'B') {
      saved_color = CRGB(0, 0, 255);

    }

    if (incomingByte == '1')
      for (int i = 0; i <= 44; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }

    else if (incomingByte == '2')
      for (int i = 44; i <= 89; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '3')
      for (int i = 90; i <= 134; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }

    else if (incomingByte == '4')
      for (int i = 135; i <= 179; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '5')
      for (int i = 180; i <= 224; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '6')
      for (int i = 225; i <= 269; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '7')
      for (int i = 270; i <= 314; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
      }
    else if (incomingByte == '8')
      for (int i = 315; i <= 359; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;

      }

    FastLED.show();
  }
}
```

I'll describe the project a bit more to elaborate. It's a lamp (octagon shape) with 45 leds on the 8 sides. each side is triggered by movement and  sends a byte (`'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'8'`) to turn on one side of the lamp.

I want to be able to select the colour before sending the bytes. so I need arduino to remember the `'R'`, `'G'`, `'B'` bytes and only change when I send the other byte.

Comment: you receive bytes not 'serials'

Comment: I am sending "Bytes" from processing to arduino. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. @jsotola I edited my code

Comment: first, you need to identify the problem clearly .... the arduino is receiving data correctly, so kinect and processing are irrelevant .... next, read through your program listing .... what happens if `R` is received? ... what should happen? .... what happens if `3` is received? ... what should happen?

Comment: @jsotola clearly the problem is in the arduino code. I want to know how to remember the R,G,B bytes and how to swap between them.

Comment: I don't fully understand what is the expected and what the seen behavior. The code will change all LEDs to one color on R G or B. That what  you have programmed. On 8 only the LEDs 315 to 359 will be set to red, leaving the rest untouched. Is that unexpected?

Comment: @chrisl no, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 each do their job. they trigger 45 LEDS on one side of the octagon. but before triggering the sides I want to choose the colour they will become. I want to use RGB bytes to send to arduino, and arduino to remember them and be able to swap between them. I also edited my post

Comment: i do not understand why you are unable to set a variable to some chosen value when, for instance, `R` is received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]` only holds the current state of the LEDs. It is used to push the data out to the LEDs. If you want the code to save one color to use later, you need an extra variable, that can hold the color.

Add a variable at global scope:

```
CRGB saved_color;
```

In the `if` statements for R, G and B you can set this variable to the corresponding value, for example:

```
if(incomingByte == 'R'){
    saved_color = CRGB(255,0,0);
}
```

And in the `if` statements of 1 to 8 you can use this value, for example:

```
if (incomingByte == '1'){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 44; i++) {
        leds[i] = saved_color;
    }
}
```

Note: The above code does not change any LEDs on R, G or B. They just set the color for future operation 1 to 8.

Comment: Okay, and how do I make it switch? would that be with the else if statement? I have updated my post to show my code with your tips

Comment: What do you mean? You would send R, G or B to select the corresponding color (red, green, blue) for the future action 1 to 8. So if you send an R, the lamp will have the color red preset (not lighting up). If you then send 4, the side 4 will light up in red. If you then send 2, side 2 will light up in red. If you then send G, the internal preset will be set to green (not changing the lights yet). If you then send 5, side 5 will light up in green.

Comment: nevermind sir, I spoke too soon. it's working now bro!!! thank you so much